# Weird Proc error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, ruby-1.9.2

I have a method accepting a lambda which will be called or a string which will be evaluated.
Why does the following method fail:

```
def test(expr)
  expr = expr.respond_to?(:call) ? expr : ->{ eval(expr) }
  expr.call
end

test 'puts 1'
# => TypeError: can't convert Proc into String
```

But this one work:

```
def test(expr)
  foo = expr
  expr = expr.respond_to?(:call) ? expr : ->{ eval(foo) }
  expr.call
end

test 'puts 1'
# => 1
```

Comment: Just making sure.  Glad to see you got two good answers.

Comment: @Ray: It wouldn't have been nearly as much fun if it was just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In here:

```
expr = expr.respond_to?(:call) ? expr : ->{ eval(expr) }
```

You end up with a Proc in `expr` that is a closure over `expr` so when the Proc is evaluated, it tries to `eval` itself because the `expr` inside the lambda is the lambda itself.

In here:

```
foo  = expr
expr = expr.respond_to?(:call) ? expr : ->{ eval(foo) }
```

the closure is over `foo` which refers to the original String value of `expr` so there is no funky self-referential confusion and you'll end up using `eval` on a String.

Comment: @ream88: Victor was in first so you should give him the checkmark (I won't take it personally, honest), I was just trying clarify what was going on.

Comment: +1 for calling out "self-referential".  (Also upvoted Victor for being correct _and_ first.)

Comment: Yeah, but your answer is much easier to understand ;) (Upvoted victors answer)

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning lambda to variable `expr`. That lambda tries to eval content of variable `expr` (i.e. tries to eval itself). `eval` expects only string, that is why exception is raised.